# Using ManyToManyField through and ensuring DatabaseIntegrity

Tags: django, django-orm

I have two models a teacher and a student. I also have two more models a class and a Lesson where lesson is the actual topic and class is used to dividing students. I want to create the following relations.

```
A teacher teaches a specific lesson in a specific class e.g Mike teaches python in C3
```

and

```
A student attends a class with a specific lesson e.g George is taking Python in C3
```

so eventualy

```
George is Mike's student in python in C3
```

I used a manytomany fields in both models using an intermediate model. Many to many because a teacher can have many classes where he can teach many lessons and a class may have many teachers teaching different lessons (same for students)

so I did the following:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    teaches = models.ManyToManyField(Class, through=TeacherTeaches)

class TeacherTeaches(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)
    class = models.ForeignKey(Class)
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson)
```

and for student:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    attends = models.ManyToManyField(Class, through=StudentAttends)


class StudentAttends(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    class = models.ForeignKey(Class)
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson)
```

But what I think it can't be done with this implementation is to make sure that the same lesson isn't taught at the same class by two different Teachers, correct?Because of the ForeignKey(I think). Is there a better way to "set up" my models to achieve the above behaviour? Should I "unite" the two intermediate models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to approach it from the other direction to limit the many-to-many relationships.  A class (or room, because you can't use the keyword `class` as an identifier) can only have one lesson and one teacher, so:

```
class Room(Model):
    teacher = ForeignKey(Teacher)
    lesson = ForeignKey(Lesson)
```

A teacher can teach multiple lessons, but only in one room, so this can already be queried from the `Room` model, e.g.:

```
Teacher.objects.select_related().values('lesson')
```

A student can have multiple lessons, rooms and teachers, so there is not way to avoid the many-to-many relationship, but the lessons and teachers are already related by the room, so creating a many-to-many with the room will be the simplest way.  This can be done from either side, so the model becomes:

```
class Room(Model):
    teacher = ForeignKey(Teacher)
    lesson = ForeignKey(Lesson)
    students = ManyToManyField(Student)
```

Now, ensuring that the teacher and lesson are unique is as simple as adding the appropriate constraint:

```
class Room(Model):
    teacher = ForeignKey(Teacher)
    lesson = ForeignKey(Lesson)
    students = ManyToManyField(Student)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('teacher', 'lesson')
```